# Сравнение предыдущего значения с текущим

Tags: sql-server

Создана CTE, из которой выходит выборка из 3 столбцов(name, date, value)
Мне необходимо получить только те записи из выборки у которых value предыдущей записи не совпадало с value текущей

Comment: Это так не работает. Для начала отсортируйте, пронумеруйте и соедините это так чтоб предыдущий не совпадал с текушим.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.